# Does encrypting the message protect it against length extension attacks

Tags: authentication, cryptography, hmac

Assuming the following HMAC is used : `HMACK(M) = Hash(K||M) = H` which is "secret-prefix" hashed function. M is the plaintext message , K is the secret key used

The ciphertext is generated as follow : `Ciphertext = EK(M||H)` where EK is a encryption scheme which uses the secret Key K.

I have read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) that a length extension attacks works on hashes where the secret key length and message is known. In this case as I have encrypted the message , I would like to confirm that it is no longer possible to conduct a length extension attack as M is unknown because I have encrypted it.

I am also like to know  if the above scheme used to authenticate messages is susceptible to any other attacks ??

Comment: That wouldn’t be [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Comment: Why don't you use a canonical MAC construct instead of building your own?

Comment: @dillinur i am just wondering

Comment: First rule of Cryptography - Don't Roll Your Own: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/915/485

Comment: This should prevent the length extension, but as Xander noted using MAC-then-encryption causes other difficulties, so it's still a bad idea. If the encryption is a stream cipher (including AES-CTR) it's probably secure, if it's CBC you're almost certainly fucked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does several things wrong.   First, as Rory mentions in the comments, Don't Roll Your Own.  Use HMAC, not an arbitrary hash function.   This will *actually* protect you against length extension attacks.

Second, you propose to encrypt your pseudo-MAC along with the message. Don't do this either.  This is called MAC-then-encrypt, and it leaves you potentially susceptible to attacks on the padding like the POODLE attack that just killed SSLv3.   The current standard is encrypt-then-MAC, and you need to include *both* the IV and the ciphertext of the message in the MAC to ensure that there can be no tampering.

So, you can either encrypt-then-MAC with HMAC, or better yet, just use an authenticated encryption mode that handles the implementation for you, like AES-GCM, and you don't have to worry about whether you've done it securely or not, because someone else has already handled those details for you.